# Enum and Nhibernate

Tags: nhibernate

Is it possble to use an Enum with Nhibernate? If so How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can.

In your XML  mapping file

```
<property type="Namespace.EnumClass, Namespace" 
                            name="EnumValue" column="columnName"></property>
```

[Example 1](http://codebetter.com/blogs/jeremy.miller/archive/2006/02/20/138732.aspx)

[Example 2](http://orand.blogspot.com/2006/12/generic-nhibernate-enum-string-mapping.html)